# Include loop counter in object name [VBA]

Tags: vba, loops, count

Basically I wrote a code, which is to be used in userform. The thing is that userform is created by other macro (amount of checkboxes differs, depends how many words string strNamn contains, that is why userform must be created by macro).

I would like to, somehow, include loop counter in the line:
**If UserForm1.CheckBox0.Value = True Then**
to make it like this:
**If UserForm1.CheckBox(i).Value = True Then**

But it obviously doesn't work like this :(

Any suggestion how to declare checkbox to include the counter in the line?

Code in UserForm1 to execute macro looks like:

```
Private Sub cmd_1_Click()
    Call clicker
End Sub
```

Macro code:

```
Sub clicker()
Dim strNamnOK As String
Dim strNamn As String
Dim strNamnA() As String
strNamn = "one, two, three, four"
strNamnA = Split(strNamn, ", ")
Dim intAmount As Integer
intAmount = UBound(strNamnA)
strNamnOK = ""
For i = 0 To intAmount
If UserForm1.CheckBox0.Value = True Then
strNamnOK = strNamnOK & " " & strNamnA(i)
End If
Next
strNamnOK = Left(strNamnOK, 12)
MsgBox strNamnOK
End Sub
```

Comment: you can use the controls collection:  UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & CStr(i)).Value

Comment: YOU ARE GENIUS! Thank you!